# How to get total "income" according to both "gender" and " age_group" ? Income itself is not a column, it was created by query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have three tables and I made the relation between them but couldn't get what I want.
Could you please help with the query below?

*App_Purchase_001*, *App_Purchase_002* and *App_Purchase_003* are the purchasements(*income*)

I've added **event_name_id** column to the original *product* table

Tables are:

```
select * from account
```

There are 80 rows

| *user_id* | *device_id* | *age* | *gender* |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User_000001 | Device_001 | 44 | Female |  |
| User_000002 | Device_002 | 46 | Female |  |
| User_000003 | Device_003 | 24 | Male |  |
| User_000004 | Device_004 | 47 | Female |  |
| User_000005 | Device_005 | 29 | Male |  |
| User_000006 | Device_006 | 55 | Male |  |
| User_000007 | Device_007 | 30 | Female |  |
| User_000008 | Device_008 | 22 | Female |  |
| User_000009 | Device_009 | 45 | Male |  |

```
select * from event
```

There are 22720 rows

| *user_id* | *device_id* | *event_name* | *event_time* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User_000058 | Device_058 | Puzzle_Finish_004 | 2022-11-01 00:01:00.0000000 |
| User_000033 | Device_033 | Bonus_Activation_001 | 2022-11-01 00:04:00.0000000 |
| User_000078 | Device_078 | Puzzle_Finish_005 | 2022-11-01 00:05:00.0000000 |
| User_000074 | Device_074 | Leaderboard_Open | 2022-11-01 00:10:00.0000000 |
| User_000032 | Device_032 | Level_Lose | 2022-11-01 00:12:00.0000000 |
| User_000015 | Device_015 | Puzzle_Finish_007 | 2022-11-02 22:54:00.0000000 |
| User_000035 | Device_035 | Bonus_Activation_003 | 2022-11-06 17:49:00.0000000 |
| User_000039 | Device_039 | Puzzle_Finish_011 | 2022-11-09 11:35:00.0000000 |
| User_000070 | Device_070 | App_Purchase_001 | 2022-11-11 17:55:00.0000000 |
| User_000031 | Device_031 | Puzzle_Finish_009 | 2022-11-11 18:51:00.0000000 |
| User_000019 | Device_019 | Puzzle_Finish_006 | 2022-11-11 11:36:00.0000000 |
| User_000034 | Device_034 | Puzzle_Finish_007 | 2022-11-03 19:07:00.0000000 |
| User_000019 | Device_019 | Puzzle_Finish_007 | 2022-11-06 12:36:00.0000000 |
| User_000038 | Device_038 | Puzzle_Finish_003 | 2022-11-08 02:27:00.0000000 |
| User_000077 | Device_077 | Puzzle_Finish_001 | 2022-11-11 11:46:00.0000000 |
| User_000064 | Device_064 | Level_Draw | 2022-11-05 01:38:00.0000000 |
| User_000059 | Device_059 | Puzzle_Finish_004 | 2022-11-09 20:44:00.0000000 |
| User_000043 | Device_043 | Puzzle_Finish_002 | 2022-11-01 01:01:00.0000000 |
| User_000055 | Device_055 | Puzzle_Finish_007 | 2022-11-05 03:19:00.0000000 |
| User_000005 | Device_005 | Puzzle_Finish_001 | 2022-11-02 05:05:00.0000000 |
| User_000003 | Device_003 | Puzzle_Finish_001 | 2022-11-03 11:49:00.0000000 |
| User_000061 | Device_061 | App_Purchase_001 | 2022-11-09 13:32:00.0000000 |
| User_000023 | Device_023 | Puzzle_Finish_005 | 2022-11-10 11:43:00.0000000 |
| User_000025 | Device_025 | Crash | 2022-11-06 11:09:00.0000000 |
| User_000053 | Device_053 | Puzzle_Finish_008 | 2022-11-05 22:02:00.0000000 |
| User_000072 | Device_072 | Puzzle_Finish_004 | 2022-11-03 17:18:00.0000000 |
| User_000037 | Device_037 | Level_Win | 2022-11-04 13:38:00.0000000 |
| User_000015 | Device_015 | Puzzle_Finish_005 | 2022-11-07 08:52:00.0000000 |
| User_000049 | Device_049 | Puzzle_Finish_005 | 2022-11-04 18:22:00.0000000 |
| User_000076 | Device_076 | Puzzle_Finish_011 | 2022-11-05 16:17:00.0000000 |
| User_000067 | Device_067 | Puzzle_Finish_011 | 2022-11-05 23:30:00.0000000 |
| User_000008 | Device_008 | Puzzle_Finish_001 | 2022-11-08 04:10:00.0000000 |
| User_000012 | Device_012 | Level_Draw | 2022-11-09 05:35:00.0000000 |
| User_000019 | Device_019 | Puzzle_Finish_010 | 2022-11-10 03:02:00.0000000 |
| User_000069 | Device_069 | Puzzle_Finish_001 | 2022-11-07 23:39:00.0000000 |
| User_000005 | Device_005 | Bonus_Activation_003 | 2022-11-02 02:47:00.0000000 |
| User_000080 | Device_080 | Puzzle_Finish_007 | 2022-11-08 12:30:00.0000000 |
| User_000058 | Device_058 | App_Purchase_003 | 2022-11-02 12:52:00.0000000 |
| User_000035 | Device_035 | Puzzle_Finish_011 | 2022-11-08 10:48:00.0000000 |
| User_000003 | Device_003 | Puzzle_Finish_005 | 2022-11-10 20:05:00.0000000 |
| User_000006 | Device_006 | Level_Draw | 2022-11-03 21:22:00.0000000 |
| User_000034 | Device_034 | Crash | 2022-11-10 04:08:00.0000000 |
| User_000070 | Device_070 | Puzzle_Finish_006 | 2022-11-02 07:30:00.0000000 |
| User_000073 | Device_073 | Puzzle_Finish_012 | 2022-11-06 22:34:00.0000000 |
| User_000052 | Device_052 | Puzzle_Finish_009 | 2022-11-02 07:47:00.0000000 |
| User_000028 | Device_028 | Puzzle_Finish_006 | 2022-11-05 11:34:00.0000000 |
| User_000077 | Device_077 | Level_Win | 2022-11-11 02:25:00.0000000 |
| User_000077 | Device_077 | Crash | 2022-11-06 03:50:00.0000000 |
| User_000064 | Device_064 | Puzzle_Finish_006 | 2022-11-09 13:15:00.0000000 |
| User_000012 | Device_012 | Bonus_Activation_002 | 2022-11-09 03:11:00.0000000 |
| User_000060 | Device_060 | Puzzle_Finish_007 | 2022-11-04 00:59:00.0000000 |
| User_000049 | Device_049 | Bonus_Activation_001 | 2022-11-10 19:30:00.0000000 |
| User_000025 | Device_025 | App_Purchase_003 | 2022-11-09 16:39:00.0000000 |
| User_000043 | Device_043 | Puzzle_Finish_002 | 2022-11-11 00:06:00.0000000 |
| User_000008 | Device_008 | Puzzle_Finish_012 | 2022-11-07 10:22:00.0000000 |
| User_000080 | Device_080 | Puzzle_Finish_005 | 2022-11-05 09:23:00.0000000 |
| User_000035 | Device_035 | Leaderboard_Open | 2022-11-09 16:10:00.0000000 |
| User_000074 | Device_074 | Bonus_Activation_001 | 2022-11-04 16:51:00.0000000 |
| User_000062 | Device_062 | Crash | 2022-11-07 03:47:00.0000000 |
| User_000066 | Device_066 | App_Purchase_001 | 2022-11-04 18:11:00.0000000 |
| User_000066 | Device_066 | Bonus_Activation_003 | 2022-11-01 19:44:00.0000000 |
| User_000028 | Device_028 | Puzzle_Finish_001 | 2022-11-04 00:48:00.0000000 |
| User_000031 | Device_031 | Ping | 2022-11-08 17:40:00.0000000 |
| User_000003 | Device_003 | Puzzle_Finish_006 | 2022-11-03 03:26:00.0000000 |
| User_000025 | Device_025 | Puzzle_Finish_012 | 2022-11-09 19:48:00.0000000 |
| User_000075 | Device_075 | Level_Lose | 2022-11-10 03:07:00.0000000 |
| User_000042 | Device_042 | Puzzle_Finish_010 | 2022-11-08 03:36:00.0000000 |
| User_000061 | Device_061 | Puzzle_Finish_002 | 2022-11-02 11:39:00.0000000 |
| User_000053 | Device_053 | App_Purchase_001 | 2022-11-08 03:28:00.0000000 |
| User_000074 | Device_074 | Level_Win | 2022-11-02 03:45:00.0000000 |
| User_000026 | Device_026 | Puzzle_Finish_005 | 2022-11-06 02:08:00.0000000 |
| User_000074 | Device_074 | Puzzle_Finish_004 | 2022-11-06 13:26:00.0000000 |
| User_000001 | Device_001 | Puzzle_Finish_005 | 2022-11-06 08:05:00.0000000 |
| User_000063 | Device_063 | Puzzle_Finish_012 | 2022-11-05 00:09:00.0000000 |
| User_000057 | Device_057 | Puzzle_Finish_003 | 2022-11-09 22:53:00.0000000 |

```
select * from product
```

| *product_id* | *price* | *skin_color* | _event_name_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | Red | App_Purchase_001 |
| 2 | 10 | Blue | App_Purchase_002 |
| 3 | 15 | NULL | App_Purchase_003 |

What I want:

| age_group | gender | income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-18 | Male | 680 |

My Query so far is:

```
Select A._gender_, count (E._event_name_) * P._price_ As "income ",
       (CASE WHEN A._age_ BETWEEN 0 AND 18 THEN '0-18'
             WHEN A._age_ BETWEEN 19 AND 24 THEN '19-24'
             WHEN A._age_ BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN '25-30'
             WHEN A._age_ BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
             WHEN A._age_ BETWEEN 41 AND 55 THEN '41-55'
        END ) AS age_group
from event E,
     Account A,
     Product P
where _event_name_ in ('App_Purchase_001' , 'App_Purchase_002' , 'App_Purchase_003') and
      E._device_id_ = A._device_id_ and E._event_name_ = P._event_name_id and A._gender_ = 'Male'
   or A._gender_='Female'
group by A._age_, P._price_, A._gender_
```

Output to this query is:

| *gender* | income | age_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 85 | 0-18 |
| Male | 190 | 0-18 |
| Male | 405 | 0-18 |
| Female | 113600 | 19-24 |
| Female | 227200 | 19-24 |
| Female | 340800 | 19-24 |
| Female | 113600 | 19-24 |

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Remove the unrelated tag.)

Comment: There's no correlated subquery here, so you can remove that tag too.

Comment: isn't this just a case of putting a SUM wrapper around "count (E._event_name_)* P._price_" and then adding a GROUP BY A._gender_ and your CASE statement?

Comment: And please don't use images to display data - use formatted text

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags. You'll need to [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using (along with removing the images and repacing them with consumable text).

Comment: Please add proper tags.

Comment: So sorry for the tags, I am new

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (It's 2023 now...)

Comment: @jarlh It is MS-SQL Server 2017, thank you for the tip, I will improve my code.

Comment: @RickyTillson yes it should be that easy, but sql doesn't allow me to put sum before the count

Comment: @DaleK I have edited, hope it s fine now

Comment: @Gulizar can you select your Gender, Income and Age_Group into a CTE, then sum it all up when selecting from the CTE? also at the moment your example data will return nothing because the only App_Purchase Event is for an Account you've not provided

Comment: One more time, switch to explicit JOIN and your query will be at least better. (Or add parentheses, because AND goes before OR.)

Comment: And, as already suggested, do the CASE in a derived table (or cte), before aggregating.

Comment: You need to also show us your desired results.

Comment: @jarlh I don't know how to use CTE, I will try. I will add other App Purchases

Comment: @DaleK I have showed actually, you can find it above the my query section

Comment: There are 22720 rows in event table, 80 rows in account table

Comment: @RickyTillson sorry, you have also mentioned about CTE, I didn't notice. I don't know it but I will try, and I added more app_purchase related rows

Answer (score 0):

You can write the data into a CTE to aggregate the income at an account level using something like this code. I altered the WHERE clause to use LIKE instead of listing the different purchase types so you may need to alter that to something a bit more specific:

```
;WITH CTEIndividual
AS (
    SELECT A.Gender,
           COUNT(E.EventName) * P.Price AS Income,
           (CASE
                WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 0 AND 18 THEN '0-18'
                WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 19 AND 24 THEN '19-24'
                WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN '25-30'
                WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
                WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 41 AND 55 THEN '41-55'
            END
           ) AS age_group
    FROM #TempAccount AS A
         INNER JOIN #TempEvent AS E ON E.UserID = A.UserID AND E.DeviceID = A.DeviceID
         INNER JOIN #TempProduct AS P ON E.EventName = P.EventNameID
    WHERE E.EventName LIKE 'App_Purchase%'
    GROUP BY (CASE
                  WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 0 AND 18 THEN '0-18'
                  WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 19 AND 24 THEN '19-24'
                  WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 25 AND 30 THEN '25-30'
                  WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
                  WHEN A.Age BETWEEN 41 AND 55 THEN '41-55'
              END
             ),
             A.Gender,
             P.Price
)
```

Then you can sum it all up using something like this:

```
SELECT C.Gender,
       SUM(C.Income) AS Income,
       C.age_group
FROM CTEIndividual AS C
GROUP BY C.Gender,
         C.age_group
ORDER BY C.Gender DESC,
         C.age_group;
```

Comment: Many thanks. It gives an error in the first code block, in group by section. "Incorrect syntax near ')'." I removed "," before the A.Gender, but then gave error near A. "Incorrect syntax near 'A'." Why does this happen? Tried a couple things to fix it , but the error loop stayed between ) and A.

Comment: my tables might not be exactly the same as yours, I created temp tables and Aliased them & my columns are slightly different because I removed the underscores

Comment: Yes, I know, I have altered your answer according to my tables&names. I thought maybe, by any chance, you have also came accross the same error. Thanks anyway